# C# interactive window command history in VS 2015 Update 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I just installed the 2nd update of VS 2015 Professional and played with the C# Interactive Window and I've been bothered a lot with the impossibility of using the Up and Down arrows to navigate through the command history (unlike in every console window I've ever used).

Browsing the web I've found some help on this matter : **Alt** + **UpArrow/DownArrow** should do the trick.
Problem is it doesn't work.
I didn't install the update 1 but went directly from the RTM version to the Update 2.

When I hover the History Previous and History Next buttons, there is no keyboard shortcut associated with these commands either, when the blog posts I've read seemed to have the shortcut indicated, like in this capture :
[image]

So my question is : have you experienced the same issue with VS 2015 Update 2 and if so, have you found a keyboard shortcut that works ?
Coding without the command history is a lot more tedious than I'd have thought, thanks for helping me !

Comment: VS 2015 Enterprise Update 1 works well, the error may be related to something else

Comment: Actually, it was Resharper's fault...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open VS Options...

Go to Environment->Keyboard Settings

Search for InteractiveConsole.HistoryNext and InteractiveConsole.HistoryPrevious
Set shortcuts you want.

(Check the keyboard mapping scheme in this dialog page - I have "Visual C# 2005" and I have these shortcuts set).

Comment: Thanks Sergey, it turns out Resharper was already mapping Alt + Up/Down and that's why the shortcut didn't work in the interactive window. I found that out while remapping it following your answer, so thanks !

Comment: @JJP - Also using Re#, did you find a way a way to get the two shortcuts to play nice together?  Seems odd that a shortcut in the code edit window would block a shortcut in a tool window.

Comment: @PhilipPittle Well, as a matter of fact, this shortcut is heavily used, and I also had the Productivity Power Tools installed so the shortcut for Resharper was already broken. I didn't use the Move Line feature and I never looked back when remapping the shortcut for the interactive console but I suggest you read this question for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673875/resharper-move-line-up-down-not-working

Comment: Good to know it is Alt+ Up/Down and that it can be changed, was looking for this shortcut for a while :) ... I tried changing to Up/Down directly (i.e. without Alt) but does not seem to be possible ... Best behavior I would have liked 1) If no text is yet typed then 'Up' navigates the full history   2) If some text is already typed then 'Up' navigates the history filtering for commands starting with the same text.